# Elementwise power returning NaN?

Tags: r

Take the following R code (intermediate lines to make reproducible)

```
set.seed(123)

ORDER <- 4

# Base R objects
Aint <- sample(seq.int(10), ORDER, replace = TRUE)
Bint <- sample(seq.int(10), ORDER, replace = TRUE)
A <- rnorm(ORDER)
B <- rnorm(ORDER)
```

If I take `A^B` I get the following output:

```
[1] 4.0759550 0.7863032 0.3874769       NaN
```

which is fine, but I am confused when I try to type the numbers directly I get a real value

```
-1.265061^0.3598138
[1] -1.088281
```

yet when I use indexing, I still get the `NaN`.

```
 A[4] ^ B[4]
[1] NaN
```

Why would I get `NaN` when the precision extends beyond what I see in the output?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317528/how-do-you-compute-negative-numbers-to-fractional-powers for a discussion of the math.

Comment: something like `(-4)^(1/2)` will give back `NaN`

Comment: Try it with parenthesis

Comment: @docendodiscimus Ah! It is just an order of operations...